# Why can the datatype of an array not be changed inside a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a structure of a list of arrays with complex entries and I want to convert them into floats. The imaginary part can be discarded, thats fine.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([2+3j,3+4j])
b=np.array([1+2j,4+3j])
arrays=[a,b]

for i,y in enumerate(arrays):
    y=y.astype('float64')

print(arrays)
```

I am wondering, why this doesn't work, while on the other hand, changing the type to float before creating the list 'arrays' does work.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([2+3j,3+4j])
b=np.array([1+2j,4+3j])
a=a.astype('float64')
b=b.astype('float64')
arrays=[a,b]
print(arrays)
```

This is a very basic question, but I would be very happy, if someone could share his or her thoughts about this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `y=y.astype('float64')` here `y` is a copy of array element. `arrays[i] = y.astype('float64')` may work.

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `astype` is not an in-place operation.  So even if you manage to change the dtype of the element is `arrays`, you won't change the dtype of the object referenced by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering, why this doesn't work ...

`y.astype('float64')` creates a new object. The assignment *in* the loop assigns that new object to the name `y`. Because of the assignment `y` no longer points to the array item so the array item is not changed.

If you were performing an operation in the loop that modified the item *in-place* it would work like you expected. ...

```
for i,y in enumerate(arrays):
    np.add(y,4,out=y)
```

Whereas `for i,y in enumerate(arrays): y = y + 4` will behave like the example in your question.